# JavaScript/Node.js JSON.parse() Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I am receiving the error:

```
undefined:1
'{"completed_in":0.078,"max_id":333655176038719488,"max_id_str":"3336551760387
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /home/tweets/10seconds.js:25:25
    at passBackControl (/home/tweets/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:367:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/tweets/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:386:9)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:895:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

When parsing Twitter API JSON from the Search API.

The code I am using the parse this JSON is:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db", function(err, db) {

 if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
  var collection = db.collection("tweets");

    while(run < 200){

        oa.get("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=morning&rpp=100&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed", access_token, access_token_secret, function(error, data) {
            var theTweets = JSON.parse(sys.inspect(data));

           collection.insert(theTweets, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});
           console.log(run);
        });
    run = run + 1;
    }

});
```

What could cause this?

Comment: Why are you `sys.inspect()`ing `data`? I would expect `data` is either JSON, so you should just `JSON.parse(data)`, or it's already a native JS object, so you don't need to parse it at all.

Comment: @MattBall, heh... almost same message =P

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the output of `sys.inspect` is not JSON it adds the quote `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `sys.inspect`?

If data is a JSON string, then use `JSON.parse(data);` and if it's an `object` already, well you don't have to use `JSON.parse` at all...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the sys.inspect() call as already stated by the other answers and comments.

As stated in the nodejs documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

> Return a string representation of object, which is useful for debugging.

By the way, it seems they changed the *sys* module name to *util*.

You can easily make a small test by running the following code on an older node version.  It should throw your error:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var data = '{"test":1, "test2":2}';
sys.puts(JSON.parse(sys.inspect(data)));
```

And then remove the sys.inspect call. It should correctly parse the object:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var data = '{"test":1, "test2":2}';
sys.puts(JSON.parse(data));
```